# Python script printouts just appearing at the end of execution when calling it externally and logging stdout/stderr into file

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I'm calling a script from another one by using:

```
command = 'python foo.py'
with open('./logs.txt', 'w') as file:
    p = Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=file, stdout=file)
    p.wait()
```

Where `foo.py` does several call for another script `bar.py`.

By doing this, unfortunately I get a behavior that I didn't want when it's writing to the text file. The printouts are getting messed up and, for some reason, `bar.py` printouts appears **before** `foo.py`, which gets messy as the code follows a linear execution and the printouts I wanted to see were executed before calling `bar.py`.

When I use `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` and Popen's `stdout` and `stderr`, respectively, I don't see this behavior happening.

Any clue why this happens?

Just to illustrate the situation, a crafted printout, when writing to external file (I will use a third script call for better exemplification):

```sh
[bar.py] This is print 1
[xyz.py] This is print 1
[foo.py] This is print 1
[foo.py] This is print 2
[foo.py] This is print 3
```

What I actually would like to see/it's happening when using sys' `stdout`/`stderr`:

```sh
[foo.py] This is print 1
[bar.py] This is print 1
[foo.py] This is print 2
[xyz.py] This is print 1
[foo.py] This is print 3
```

For the `foo.py` printouts I'm just using Python's `print()` method. Don't know about the external ones because it wasn't written by me.

Strangely this behavior happens on `docker logs` too, i.e. when I execute this chain on a container and want to see the printouts . So, I think it can be related in some way.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect this is due to [output buffering](https://www.quora.com/What-is-output-buffering-in-Python).

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182537/write-python-stdout-to-file-immediately) answer on stack exchange suggests:

> ... When process STDOUT is redirected to something other than a terminal, then the output is buffered into some OS-specific-sized buffer (perhaps 4k or 8k in many cases). Conversely, when outputting to a terminal, STDOUT will be line-buffered or not buffered at all, so you'll see output after each \n or for each character

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering) may be helpful, it describes how to disable output buffering.

The easy thing to try would be to tell Python to run unbuffered with the `-u` flag:

```
command = 'python -u foo.py'
```

Comment: This solved! Thanks. Are there any heavy side effects by using this?

Comment: Without buffering, printing will take a little more overhead on the OS side. The buffering exists to put less load on the I/O, but I doubt this will be an issue unless you have a LOT of I/O with really tight time constraints.